# Search column for urls, save webpages as individual text files

Tags: vba, excel

I have code here that works for a url that is hard coded, and it only works for one url and one text file.

```
Sub saveUrl_Test()

Dim FileName As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim ieApp As Object  
Dim Txt As String
Dim TxtFile As Object
Dim URL As String

    URL = "www.bing.com"
    FileName = "C:\mallet\bing.com.txt"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set TxtFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 2, True, -1)

    Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieApp.Visible = True
    ieApp.Navigate URL

    While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Txt = ieApp.Document.body.innerText
    TxtFile.Write Txt
    TxtFile.Close

    ieApp.Quit

    Set ieApp = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

What I want it to do is search in column B for urls (possibly using InStr(variable, "http://") as a boolean), and then save each webpage as an individual text file. Would there be a way to name the text files using part of the URL strings?   Also, is there a way for the webpage not to open, but still save as a  text file? Opening the webpages wastes a lot of time.

I created this additional sub based on @MikeD's suggestion, but I get the wend without while error.

```
Sub url_Test(URL As String, FileName As String)

Dim FSO As Object
Dim ieApp As Object
Dim Txt As String
Dim TxtFile As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set TxtFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 2, True, -1)

    Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieApp.Visible = True
    ieApp.Navigate URL

    While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Txt = ieApp.Document.body.innerText
    TxtFile.Write Txt
    TxtFile.Close

    ieApp.Quit

    Set ieApp = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub

Sub LoopOverB()  
Dim myRow As Long

    myRow = 10

    While Cells(myRow, 2).Value <> ""

        If InStr(1, Cells(myRow, 2).Value, "http:\\", vbTextCompare) Then Call url_Test(Cells(myRow, 2).Value, "C:\mallet\test\" & Cells(myRow, 1).Value & ".txt")
        myRow = myRow + 1
    Wend 
End Sub
```

Comment: yeep ... you forgot the `End If` inside the lower `While ... Wend` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could parameterize the sub

```
Sub saveUrl_param(URL as String, FileName as String)
    ....
End Sub
```

and remove the `Dim` and assignment statements for `URL` and `FileName`

Secondly you write another Sub which loops through non-empty cells in column B, retrieving values and conditionally calling the `saveUrl_param()` routine.

example:

```
Sub LoopOverB()
Dim C As Range
    For Each C In Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        ' If C = .... Then ' note: URL in [B], filename in [C]
        '     saveUrl_param(C, C(1,2))
        ' End If
    Next C
End Sub
```

and no - you can't do it without opening the Web page; you somehow have to get the page from the server (or the proxy). This is done by

```
ieApp.Navigate URL
```

and the following `While ... Wend` construct waits until the page is fully loaded into the browser object.

To speed up things you could skip

```
ieApp.Visible = True
```

once you have confidence that your Sub is working correctly, and you could move

```
Dim ieApp As Object ' I would prefer As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer .... don't like late binding
Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

to the calling sub and hand over the ieApp object to the subroutine as a parameter in order to not open/close the browser again & again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still pretty new to vba, so could you go into more detail about the LoopOverB subroutine and moving the ieApp?